# Tracking payments sent to scammers, and what they do with the money

Tags: transactions, payment, fraud

I am interested in tracking payments sent to [known scammers](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=126552.0), and tracing where that money goes.

Is there any website that compiles this information and shares it with others?

Answer (score 3):

There was a project that seems to no longer be active called [BlockViewer](http://toolongdidntread.com/announcement/the-future-of-blockviewer/).

The problem, of course, is Bitcoin's pseudonymous nature.  Beginning with the first transfer the trail can be essentially be blurred and the coins re-enter circulation through legitimate transactions with innocent parties.  Just like what happens when scammers use cash as well.